# Slow request times in webapi hosted in azure virtual machine

Tags: performance, azure, iis, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure is responding at 90ms avg

IIS hosted in Azure VM is responding at 2000ms avg!

What can it be done to improve the network speed of the Azure VM?

---

I have a webapi app hosted in an azure virtual machine. This app links to 20 SQL Azure databases using the elastic scale client API.

Response times from SQL Azure are good: 90ms avg on 900 simultaneous users running queries against the webapi. I know SQL Azure is responding quickly because I am logging response times at the controller level in my webapi including json deserialization of the response object.

However, in my load test I'm consistently getting response times of right around 2000ms!

So, there's a 20 time discrepancy between what SQL Azure is doing to what IIS in the virtual machine is returning. The virtual machine network speed is the bottleneck now and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I have looked through several posts and fixed the following:

- Ensure power management is set for performance instead of balanced.

However, slow performance is still there.

I have the following setup:

- Azure Virtual Machine D3 (4 cores 14GB memory). This is a 500USD per month machine... it should be pretty fast, right??
- 20 SQL Azure databases at Standard S3 Level. I'm happy with these ones delivering 90ms on 900 users... Actually I think they can support a lot more users than 900 at the 90ms response times avg but
- WebAPI from .net 4.5

I'm very happy that through sharding I have been able to improve the performance of my database searches but now the network speed of the virtual machine I'm using is degrading my overall app performance to a point that it makes it a showstopper.

Any pointers on what I might be missing would be extremely appreciated.

Cheers,

Hector

Comment: Nothing between IIS and the client can possibly take 1900ms. Your assumption is wrong. Your website is slow. Prove that by issuing requests locally using Fiddler. Also note that a D3 equivalent machine costs 50$ per month at any old webhoster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what Fiddler will reveal when I have a timer that checks how long the response object takes to be constructed.

Comment: Wanted to put this in the first reply... Here it is... As far as I can see I'm measuring correctly at the controller level. This tells me it is IIS which is taking too long to respond. Here is the code I have 
public JsonResult<SearchResult> SearchInSQLAzure(SearchCriteria sc)
{

  var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  try
  {
 var result = SearchInSQLAzure(sc, executionGUID);
 var jsonresult = Json(result);
 sw.Stop();
 Logger.Write(new LogEntry() { Message = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, Severity = Verbose });
 return result;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
 //exception handling
  }
  return null;
}

Comment: I suspect there is something outside of the timer. Also, it is important to know whether IIS on the VM responds slowly or whether it is something in the Azure fabric. Fiddler would reveal that, too.

Comment: Hi usr... thanks for you replies... It looks like it was self inflicted pain. I "refactored" my load test in visual studio and replaced .ThinkTime with a Thread.Sleep... I think the Test WebRequest was actually holding the connection to the server. Once I fixed that, the response times improved DRAMATICALLY. I'm now getting 240 ms for 2000 simultaneous users with 8 servers A2 and my 20 SQL server databases. Much better.